# How to start contributing, I have developed many libraries

Tags: ros, arduino, serial, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have developed my own Robot Operating System for raspberry pi, interfaced with an arduino controller, and have achieved full motion video at 30 fps.

I have source code for all sensors, smoke( mq2 ), temperature, robotic arm, distance, motors ( up to 30 amp )-- arduino

I have source code for serial interface, message queues, socket interfaces to android -- linux

I have source code for android interface to linux

I use UV4L for raspberry pi for video interface for android, and an extremely modified version of the open source simplemjpegviewer for android.

This was all part of a startup that just became non cost effective that has recently been dissolved.

My background c/c++ linux/windows programmer for 20+ years, android 4 yrs now.

I would like to contribute some of my work to your project

Please let me know what to do

some videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HFvNOiNvUGU, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V31k7JzjMCI.

Frank Mancini

---

Edit: I have linux c code, arduino scratch code for the sensors, and android ( java ) source code.

It might be best to use them as a starting point for other programmers to implement their own solutions, or their own additions to ROS.

Probably the best use would be generic open source libraries, and even a tutorial to use UV4L.

The serial interface can be seperated out.

I have code to generate a mime formatted email with attachments.

This whole system is written in C using linux, jessie debian, developed on UBUNTU.

All of the C code is portable to any POSIX system.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249577/how-to-start-contributing,-i-have-developed-many-libraries/) by [frankmancininb](https://answers.ros.org/users/28752/frankmancininb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-07**:
This could be interesting, but could you give us an idea of how you'd like to see your libraries used? In ROS nodes, as more generic open-source libraries, is everything Arduino only or portable to other systems, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A first step would be to open source the code from the project somewhere (github, bitbucket, any other git hoster?).
Then you could send a mail e.g. to the ros-users list and tell people to have a look at it.
Without open source, there's not much to contribute to an open source project. :)
Especially when you are unsure about where the ROS community *could* benefit from it.

This sounds interesting.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2016-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frankmancininb](https://answers.ros.org/users/28752/frankmancininb/) on 2016-12-08**:
Where do I find the ros users list?  My system was meant to run headless, and only on the pi or other compatible linux board.  I also have lots of code for arduino sensors, servos and motor shields.

The system is speedy on the pi, i achieved 30 fps 320x240 mjpeg streaming with great motor response.

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2016-12-08**:
Sorry to confuse you with the name. "ros-users" was a mailinglist that recently became part of https://discourse.ros.org/ .
So best to post it there (with a link to your code, that is).